# Paste image on interactive map using two known points

Tags: python, geometry, geolocation, gps, folium

I have an interesting open-ended problem.

I have an image like the following:

[image]

The red and purple dots are points with known GPS location. I am trying to find the GPS location of the green point. A simple approximation could be made by pasting this image onto an interactive map (like Folium), aligning the red and purple dots with the GPS locations they are known to hold, and just clicking on the green dot to get its point. This approximation is good enough if these points are close to one another in real life, e.g. dots are just ~30 m away from each other.

However, the math seems very hard to align this picture with a map programatically, even though the fact that the image is uniquely constrained to a position is true. I'm looking for suggestions that can decrease the complexity of this problem. Any help would be appreciated. I don't want solutions that find the GPS position of other points on the image, otherwise I could just get the GPS position of the target. I want to use the data from the map explicitly.

I've added a Python tag because that is my preference, but it can be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the locations of the dots: `r`, `b` and `g`
We can introduce a coordinate system:

- origin - `r`
- unit vector X - `b-r`
- unit vector Y - `rotate(b-r,90degrees)=(b.y-r.y,r.x-b.x)`

If we assume that the image is an affine transformation of the real map (and ignore non-flatness of Earth :) ), then the coordinates of the green point will be the same in such CS on both the image and the map.

So:

1. express `g` coordinates on the image as a linear combination of `r` and `b` coordinates on the image
2. replace `r` and `b` coordinates with the GPS ones
3. calculate the GPS coordinates of `g`

Comment: I really want a graphical way to do this, not a way to mathematically calculate the location. The reason is that its hard to validate the math is right, imo.

Answer (score 0):

As kevinlinxc asked for a more graphic way here is an alternative method:

1. Measure the angle between the red-blue line and the red-green line
2. Draw the red-blue line between the known positions of the red and blue dots
3. Draw the red-green line with the known angle between it and the red-blue line
4. Draw the blue-green line in the same way using information from the image
5. Find the intersection of the red-green and the blue-green lines

(though in code I would still prefer the coordinate method)